# runtime complexity for while and nested for combined

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

can someone please help me figure out the runtime complexity of:

```
public void f(int m,int n){
int i = m;
while(i > 100){
    i = i / 3;
}
for(int k = i; k >= 0; k--){
    for(int j = 1; j < n; j *= 2){
        System.out.println(k + "/t" + j);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

}

the while part I just really dont know how to approach... the nested loop in my opinion is o(in) because the outer loop runs i times and the inner loop runs n/2 times, but i got the feeling im wrong.
if you could tell me how you got t the answer and how to approach questions like this
thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, the nested for loop has a run time of `O(i*logN)` because we are multiplying `j` every iteration instead of `+`. `i` is a constant value smaller than 100

so the total runtime of the nested for loop is

```
O(i * logN) <= O(100 * logN) = O(logN)
```

How many times does the while loop run? Similarly, every iteration it's divided by 3, so the total run time of the while loop is `O(logM)` (the base is a constant so it doesn't matter, see [Big O notation Log Base 2 or Log Base 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20709267/big-o-notation-log-base-2-or-log-base-10)).

As a result, this function's runtime complexity in Big O notation is 
`O(logM + logN)`